# Gesture animation on UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview, gesture

I have a simple view where I have:

- 1 `UITextView`
- 2 buttons, one left and one right

In `UITextView` I load an array with a lot of strings (texts) and when I click on the left button I have new text and the same where I click on the right button. This is working OK.

I put a gesture recognizer to the left and right and have the same code as the button. This is working OK too.

What I want to do is put some animation on gesture recognizer, is possible to put animation on `UITextView` "transaction"?

How I do this?

Comment: Not an Xcode question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using a swipe gesture recognizer, you could use `transitionWithView`. Thus:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.textView
                  duration:0.4
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft
                animations:^{
                    self.textView.text = @"new value";
                }
                completion:NULL];
```

Obviously use whatever transition type or duration that works for you. For example, you might have "back" gesture (a swipe to the right) animate from left and the "forward" gesture (a swipe to the left) to animate from the right.